# How to restrict content editing using custom permission hook?

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7

I'm using View Bulk Operations (VBO) to allow updating on a few specific fields of a custom content type.  I've created a custom permission "Can assign task" to access this feature, however in order for the update to save my user currently also has the permission

```
custom type: Edit any content
```

I can see this as a potential security vulnerability as I only want the user to be able to edit this content using the VBO and not be able to go into the content type and use the "edit" button.

Any thoughts on how to address this?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this module which really helps me!!

[Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)